# Celery workers not filling concurrency slots

Tags: python, celery, celery-task, celeryd

I have one worker with a concurrency of 4.  I see 4 processes started in flower and everything looks good.

If I do this in a shell then I see the 4 workers take the tasks and the rest are reserved and it processes 4 at a time until the queue is empty.

```
[my_task.apply_async() for i in xrange(10)]
```

However if I do this line by line only the first two tasks gets actively worked on and from then on out it processes only two at a time.

```
my_task.apply_async()
my_task.apply_async()
my_task.apply_async()
my_task.apply_async()
...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How long does a task takes to complete?

Answer (score 3):

Usually this is because of subprocesses filling up the concurrency slots. Celery uses by default prefork as the execution pool, and everytime you spawn a subprocess of a task (another fork), it counts as a running process to fill up the concurrency slots.

The simplest way to avoid this is by [using eventlet](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/concurrency/eventlet.html), which will allow you to spawn multiple async calls on each task. However, this requires that none of your tasks have blocking calls, such as `subprocess.communicate`, as they will block all tasks.

Otherwise, if you have necessary blocking calls, and you know your tasks only will have one running subprocess at a time, you can set the `CELERYD_CONCURRENCY` to the double (`8`) and set a start time-limit on your tasks, so 8 tasks won't get started right away (e.g. with `@app.task(rate_limit='10/m')`). However, this is bit of a hack, and using eventlet would definitely be preferred.